# change a value based on other value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If `product type == option`, I replace the value in the PRICE column with the value of the STRIKE column.

How can I do this without using the for loop? (to make it faster)

Now I have the following but it's slow:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
   if df.loc[i,'type'] == 'Option:
       df.loc[i,'PRICE'] = df.loc[i,'STRIKE']
```

Comment: please provide the input/output data (or examples) as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` in a vectorized fashion

```
df.loc[df['type'] == 'Option', 'PRICE'] = df['STRIKE']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
mask = (df.type == 'Option')
df[mask].PRICE = df[mask].STRIKE
```

see:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-indexing-in-pandas/

Comment: `df[mask].PRICE` is not safe because you're not guaranteed that `df[mask]` will return a view and not a copy and so the potential for failure to update exists as if `df[mask]` returns a copy the updated values will not be reflected in `df`.